# Is it possible to have your discord bot kick someone automatically without a mention?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a bot that kicks someone after they say a specific word, but I don't want to have to mention the user after I say the word. This is my code so far:

```
    case 'ok':
        
        const user = message.member

        if (user) {
            const member = message.guild.member(user);

            if (member){
                member.kick('Banned').then(() =>{
                    message.reply(`Banned`)
                })
            }
        }
        break;
}})const PREFIX = '';
```

Is there some way to make the bot automatically kick the user after they say the case word "ok"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), then kick them using [`GuildMember.kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick) as you are now.

```js
// in your existing message event
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content.includes('ok')) // if the content includes 'ok'
  message.member.kick().catch(console.error); // kick the member
});
```

I would recommend reading the full [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/), as it can help you find a greater understanding of the discord.js library, and how to use it with javascript.